# How do I place a script with SNAP svg into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to place a SNAP svg script into a div and am lost as to how I should do this.
Right now here is the html I am working with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>OH SNAP SVG 2014</title>
<script src="Snap.svg-0.1.0/dist/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    background:#FFF;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<script>



var paper= Snap(700,600);






var c = paper.image("clock machine.svg", 200,100,500,480);



var b = paper.image("new years ball.svg", 406,20,200,200);



var p = paper.image("button.svg", 258,508,35,35);



var l = paper.image("lights.svg",406,20,200,200);





var g = paper.group(b,l);

 var clickFunc= p.click 
g.transform("R90");
p.click(function(){
        g.animate({transform : "t0,227" }, 5000, mina.easein );
        T.animate({transform : "t-2557,0,"}, 4900,mina.linear);
});


    g.attr({x:250})






var T = paper.image("LCD Text.svg", 620,453,2500,85).attr({
fill: "#3FFF9B"

});

var c = paper.rect(365, 454, 263, 85, 3).attr({mask:T,
fill:"#3FFF9B"
});




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That is what I have so far. Does anybody know how I would specifically put this into a div? I read the documentation and have tried a couple of things, but my results have been futile.
Any help would be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an svg tag inside the div and attach to that, so it would look something like...

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <svg id="mysvg"></svg>
</div>

s = Snap("#mysvg");
s.rect(100,100,200,200);
```

example jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YkDz5/1/) showing the above with css on the div.

Comment: Thanks Ian! However, Now I have another problem. When I want to add another div with some text after the div with the SVG loaded, the new div with text doesn't clear and instead appears above the SVG. How can I get the divs to recognize each other and clear properly? I tried adding display block to both divs, but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle (you can edit the one above and then save)?

Comment: here's a link to the page from my website http://peterlum.co/work/SNAP.html .It's a different page, but I have transferred the exact code from the example above. for some reason it looks different in FF and Chrome but also when reloaded in chrome the loaded svg objects move for some reason as well down the y-axis. Most importantly, do you know what I need to do to be able to position them precisely within a div and also to give the SVG attributes such that the divs for the text that are currently shown above, will clear the SVG object and show below the SVG? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Not sure which text you mean, but just put the div you want first, first in the html ?

Comment: There's the fiddle. The resources arent there, but that's what I have basically for my code. You'll notice it there or if you inspect the elements from the website I included earlier that I have the div with the SVG object above the divs with the paragraphs and footer content in the HTML, but the above SVG object still appears below those 2 divs. Why is this occurring? Also I'm having trouble positioning it exactly. Are there ways to adjust where the SVG object is positioned within the SVG tags?